# Skip iteration of loop if certain value exists

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, foreach, iteration

I have the following code below that iterates through rows of a specific range and if a value is present (code not seen), creates copies of the entire pages.  My concern is at the bottom of the code in the iteration of r1. It originally only had one conditional statement...

`If BiDiRowValid(r1)`

and I wanted to add a second conditional statement, which I did...

```
and Range("MAIN_BIDI_PINMC") <> "No BiDi"
```

but when I run the code and the MAIN_BIDI_PINMC range = "No BiDi", it errors out and doesn't get past that line.  FYI:  IsBiDiRowValid() is a function that checks to see that the specific r1 is not empty, and then continues.  Right after that subroutine finishes and exits, my code errors with a "Type Mismatch error".  I also added the `ElseIf` line at the bottom, I have not gotten to that code because the top errors out, but I just want to make sure I am writing this iteration correctly, and if anything else needs to be done.  Basically, if "NoBiDi" is found in the range, I want it to skip all of this code and go to the next r1... which is what I think I have written... Thanks in advance!

```
Private Sub start_new()
    Dim MC_List As Range
    Dim r1 As Range
    Dim biDiPinName As Range
    Dim Pin As String
    Dim mc As String
    Dim mType As String
    Dim tabName As String
    Dim rowNumber As Integer
    Dim pinmcSplit() As String
    Dim NoBidi As String

On Error GoTo start_biDi_tr_new_Error



    Set MC_List = Range("MAIN_PINMC_TABLE")
        Set biDiPinName = Range("MAIN_PIN2_NAME")



 For Each r1 In MC_List.Rows
        If IsBiDiRowValid(r1) And WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("MAIN").Range("MAIN_BIDI_PINMC", "No Bidi") = 0 Then
            tabName = r1.Cells(1, 8)
            pinmcSplit = Split(tabName, "_")
            Pin = pinmcSplit(0)
            mc = pinmcSplit(1)
            mType = r1.Cells(1, 3)
        ElseIf WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("MAIN").Range("MAIN_BIDI_PINMC"), "No Bidi") = 1 Then
        End If
         Next
```

Comment: That is because `Range("MAIN_BIDI_PINMC")` is not a single cell I guess?

Comment: Correct. It is a range of cells.  Is there a way for me to access each particular cell value in that range? Perhaps iterate through that range as well?  I tried adding .value to the end, thinking that may access each particular value.  But don't think that is correct either

Comment: Use `Application.Worksheetfunction.Countif` to check for the existence of that word :)

Comment: `If IsBiDiRowValid(r1) And Application.Worksheetfunction.Countif(Range("MAIN_BIDI_PINMC"),"No BiDi") = 0 Then`

Comment: It means not found. Read about `Countif` in excel help :)

Comment: Yes that was a dumb question haha I deleted it right after I asked, forgot Count was in there.  Ok I will test TY

Comment: I posted an answer. You may have to refresh the page to see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting that error because `Range("MAIN_BIDI_PINMC")` is not a single cell. To check for a value in multiple cells you can use `Application.Worksheetfunction.Countif`

**EDIT**

Post discussion in chat, the user wanted to loop through each cell.

```
Dim aCell As Range

For Each r1 In MC_List.Rows
    If IsBiDiRowValid(r1) Then
        For Each aCell In Worksheets("MAIN").Range("MAIN_BIDI_PINMC")
            If aCell.Value <> "No Bidi" Then
                tabName = r1.Cells(1, 8)
                pinmcSplit = Split(tabName, "_")
                Pin = pinmcSplit(0)
                mc = pinmcSplit(1)
                mType = r1.Cells(1, 3)
            End If
        Next
    ElseIf aCell.Value = "No Bidi" Then
        '~~> Do Something
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I am using my code edited above. I threw the line changed with the two conditionals into the "Watches" to see what the values were seperately.  The code was tested on a pin that did not say "No Bidi", but was rather a numeric value. The Watch is telling me that the IsBiDiRow is true, but the CountIf value is False, when it should be reading as True.  It then skips to the ElseIf statement bc it isn't reading true.  I am not sure why it is reading False

Comment: What is the value of `nFound`?

Comment: I am not redefining it like you wrote in your code, I am using my edited code in my original question.  But the Application.WorksheetFunction.Countif(Range("MAIN_BIDI_PINMC"),"No BiDi") value is "FALSE" when the cell doesn't say "No Bidi" and if the cell does say "No Bidi".  Is there a way to see what cell it is evaluating?

Comment: IT should be giving you a number rather than true/false?

Comment: I understand that. The `Countif` return a long value and not a boolean value. You must be doing something wrong :)

Comment: I'm in including the = 0 part so that is why it is saying TRUE/FALSE.  If i take off = 0, it says the value = 1, which is wrong bc the first cell is numeric and the second cell down is the No Bidi cell.  It doesn't look like it's iterating through the cells correctly..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61295/discussion-between-sinister-swan-and-siddharth-rout).